# How to update current meeting event using Microsoft graph?(patch method using)

Tags: java, android, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I tried to update Microsoft outlook meeting using Microsoft graph android SDK. But that is not working properly. Below code is a sample code I wrote. (get all the events API was working properly.I need to know how to work with patch method)

```
 mClient.customRequest("/users/" +abs@onmicrosoft.com+ "/calendar/events/"+meetingResponseId)
                .buildRequest()
                .patch(jsonObject);
```